# Remove item from mutable list added from a model in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, collections

In my code, I create a mutable list and add elements from a model:

```
var lista: MutableList<ExpenseItem> =  mutableListOf()
...
class ExpenseItem (val name: String, val word: String, val flavour: String)
...
      val currentExpense = ExpenseItem("Sergio", "Aguacate", "Duro")
            val currentExpense1 = ExpenseItem("amaya", "fresas", "pan")
            val currentExpense2 = ExpenseItem("emma", "limon", "agua")

            lista.add(currentExpense)
            lista.add(currentExpense1)
            lista.add(currentExpense2)
```

Now I am looking for a way to remove elements knowing, for example, the ´name´ field

I have tried the filters, remove, drop, etc for the list. I've also tried "when", but I think I'm not finding the correct syntax or way to do it,

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you looking for `lista.removeAll { it.name == nameToRemove }`?

Comment: Yes sir, thanks... I'm at the beginning with kotlin :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the method you want is

```
lista.removeAll { it.name == nameToRemove }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to modiify the actual list, then you'll want removeAll.

```
lista.removeAll {
     it.name == "nameToRemove"
}
```

If you don't want to modify the original list, then filter can you get a new list without those elements.

```
val newList = lista.filter{
     it.name != "nameToRemove"
}
```

Below shows a complete explanation of the behavior

```
var list: MutableList<String> =  mutableListOf("1","2", "3")

//Shows all items
list.forEach {
    println(it)
}

//Makes a new list with all items that are not equal to 1
val newList = list.filter {
    it != "1"
}
newList.forEach {
    println(it)
}

//Original list is untouched
list.forEach {
    println(it)
}

//Modifies this list to remove all items that are 1
list.removeAll {
    it == "1"
}
list.forEach {
    println(it)
}
```